# How to mock an interface parameter for a service method using Spock and Grails 2?

Tags: grails, spock

Given something like:

```
@TestFor(MyService)
@Mock(SomeClass)
class WhateverSpec extends Specification {
  def 'Test a mock'() {
    given:
    def someObject = new SomeClass(name: 'hello')
    assert someObject.name == 'hello'

    when:
    def result = service.doSomething(someObject)

    then:
    result == 'nice'
  }
}
```

Given `doSomething()` is defined as something like:

```
String doSomething(SomeClass thing) {
  // ...
  return 'nice'
}
```

There should be no problem. But what if the parameter in `doSomething` is an **interface**? `String doSomething(SomeInterface thing)`. How would I go about making a mock object in the test without directly creating a new SomeClass (like I am not supposed to assume what kind of object it will be, but that object will certainly implement the interface).

Comment: def interfaceMock = Mock(SomeInterface)
See http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/interaction_based_testing.html

Comment: @rgrebski why don't you answer the question? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Mock/Stub/Spy method from Specification (depends on your needs)

```
def mokedInterface = Mock(MyInterface)
```

Here is an exmple with mocking List interface:

```
def 'should mock List interface size method'() {
    given:
        def mockedList = Mock(List)
        def expectedListSize = 2
        mockedList.size() >> expectedListSize
    when:
        def currentSize = mockedList.size()
    then:
        currentSize == expectedListSize
}
```